# Email address not allowed error when pushing to remote

Tags: git

I am getting an **email address not allowed** error why pushing to the remote.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c
credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --set-upstream origin
refs/heads/feature/BROC-133_my_branch:refs/heads/feature/ROC-133_my_branch
```

Pushing to

```
ssh://git_me@git.xxx.de:222/var/lib/git/broccoli-ios.git remote:
Email address 'xxx@yyy.com' in commit 067e3d3 not allowed when
updating refs/heads/feature/ROC-133_my_branch         To
ssh://git_xxx@git.xxx.yy:222/var/lib/git/xxx-ios.git  !

[remote rejected] feature/ROC-133_xxx ->
feature/ROC-133_xxx (pre-receive hook declined) error:
failed to push some refs to
'ssh://xxx@git.xxx.yy:222/var/lib/git/xxx-ios.git'

Completed with errors, see above
```

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Configuration of the remote server?

Comment: As @choroba suggested, the `pre-receive` hook in the remote repository is rejecting your email address.  If you are not the administrator of the remote repository, you will need to find out who is and ask them about the policies associated with the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explained here:

```
feature/BROC-133_xxx (pre-receive hook declined) error:
```

Your server side `pre-receive hook` deny your email address from pushing code into the desired repo or branch.

You have to contact your git administrator to modify the hook and allowing you to commit your code.